# Raster in TOC to geotiff on disk in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, raster, netcdf

I am attempting to automate some ArcGIS10 work w/ netcdf files. Basically, I am able to automate the creation of the netcdf into a raster with `arcpy.MakeNetCDFRasterLayer_md`. However, I would simply like to then in the same python script save this layer out to a geotiff on my disk so that I can use it later in some analysis. Manually, I know I can go to the TOC right-click and export to geotiff, but it would be great to be able to script this.

I have pasted my arcpy code below for anyone’s reference which works to add the netcdf as a raster to the TOC, but I am stuck after that.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data/test/ArcGISScripting/ArcPy"

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

# Local variables:
crcm_ccsm_cdd_mean_nc = "C:\\Data\\test\\output_files\\crcm_ccsm_cdd_mean.nc"
outputRaster = "C:\\Data\\test\\ArcGISScripting\\ArcPy\\result1_Layer3.tif"

# Process: Make NetCDF Raster Layer
test = arcpy.MakeNetCDFRasterLayer_md(crcm_ccsm_cdd_mean_nc, "result1", "xc", "yc", outputRaster, "", "", "BY_VALUE")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\Data\test\ArcGISScripting\ArcPy\result1_Layer3.tif")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer, "BOTTOM")
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)[0].name
#arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(lyr, r"C:\Data\test\ArcGISScripting\ArcPy\result1_Layer3.tif"
del mxd, addLayer
#arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management("C:\\Data\\test\\ArcGISScripting\\ArcPy\\result1_Layer3.tif", "C:\\Data\\test\\ArcGISScripting\\ArcPy\\result1_Layer3.tif", "ABSOLUTE")
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to add the netcdf layer to ArcMap, skip the add to ArcMap TOC step and convert straight to tif:

```
# Local variables:
crcm_ccsm_cdd_mean_nc = "C:\\Data\\NEMAC\\Projects\\NCA\\NCANetcdfProcessing\\output_files\\crcm_ccsm_cdd_mean.nc"
outputRaster = "result1_Layer3.tif"
nc_lyr="crcm_ccsm_cdd_mean"

# Process: Make NetCDF Raster Layer
result = arcpy.MakeNetCDFRasterLayer_md(crcm_ccsm_cdd_mean_nc, "result1", "xc", "yc", nc_lyr, "", "", "BY_VALUE")
result = arcpy.CopyRaster_management(nc_lyr,outputRaster)
```